# Updating IronRuby to Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, ironruby

Since IronRuby is discontinued (frozen since 2011) I would like to upgrade the test framework I have to Ruby.
So I removed the IronRuby, installed the latest stable Ruby, and started dealing with all errors.
Everything was going well until I reached the load assemblies.

```
load_assembly 'MyAppName.UIAutomationClientSideProviders'
assembly = MyAppName::UIAutomationClientSideProviders::UIAutomationClientSideProviders.to_clr_type.assembly
```

I could not find a way to replace the load_assembly.
Have anyone been through this issue before?
Is there a way to use WIN32OLE to call the C# class?